# Why is light showing through a solid mesh object?

Tags: transparency, smoke-simulation

I'm creating an animation showing a wok with fire beneath it.  The wok is a simple model--a mesh circle that I formed into a bowl (wok) shape.  I used the quick smoke effect to create a nice fire right beneath the bowl, like the bowl/wok is on a stove top.

The problem is that the rendered image shows some of the light from the fire penetrating through the bottom of the wok.  It's not bright but, looking down at the wok, it is glowing in the area closest to the fire emitter beneath it.

How do I make the wok completely impenetrable to the the light from the fire?  Why is it allowing the light to glow through to begin with?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: There are several possible reasons. The first thing I came to think about is that you need to enable smoke collision for the bowl. It could also be that the bowl material has some translucency, transparency or subsurface scattering. Are you using Cycles or Blender Internal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the bowl a collision object for the fire. With the bowl active, in the *Physics* tab click *Smoke*, then *Collision*. The collision type should be set according to what you do with the bowl. *Static* if remains still, *Animated* if you animate it using keyframes or drivers and *Rigid* if it has rigid body physics enabled.

[image]

You may also need to increase the *Subframes* setting for the emitter, to get higher accuracy to prevent flames to pass through the bowl between frames.

[image]

Here the bowl has collision enabled.

[image]

And here is doesn't.

[image]

Comment: @Harlan If this doesn't solve the issue, it's likely that your material is partially transparent or translucent. Then you should include a screenshot of the bowl's material setup or share your .blend file. You can do the latter at [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit your question to include the link given to you once the upload is complete.

Comment: Very fast response, thank you, this is my first time using the site, and I'm new to Blender.  It turns out when I do a render by pressing the image render button, there appears to be no fire light showing through the bowl.  But when I look at the preview render in the viewport, that is where I see the light glowing through the bottom of the bowl where it is almost in contact with the emitter.  Collision is on; simple glossy material.  [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2311" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2311/)

Comment: @iggy The wok is basically made of an infinitesimally thin plate. Ideally it should work any way, even in just rendered preview, but nothing ever works ideally, does it? But adding a solidify modifier does help in this case, but it doesn't solve it completely. Some of the fire still seeps through. Increasing the either thickness value of the modifier or the number of subframes calculated for the emitter should help even further. The solidify modifier needs to be above the smoke modifier. You can change the order of the modifiers by the arrows to the right. http://i.imgur.com/xs3NLKS.png